# Leaflet using WMS with GetFeatureInfo

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geo, wms, getfeatureinfo

I'm trying to use WMS to generate a popup OR something similar to this:

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html

And I'm trying to use this plugin:

https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms

But it is not working, I'm not really understand how to use this plugin, because its documentation, although extensive, is horrible in terms of organization and makes it difficult for younger people to understand. And my doubt is also of others, because I have seen other people looking for information here, but without success. My request is: could someone help me by showing some tutorial or code in git referring to what I asked for, a simple map with WMS getting the information through getfeatureinfo and showing on the screen in a popup when clicking or hovering over.
I would like to learn or have something to base myself on, since I have also followed this tutorial and nothing:
https://gist.github.com/rclark/6908938
Thank you very much

Comment: WMS don't generate pop-ups.  WMS respond to requests from some client (for example Leaflet), and the client needs to handle where the requested response goes, such as the GetFeatureInfo request response.

Comment: For WMS questions you're probably better going to https://gis.stackexchange.com/